# SSIS .Net package fails and then will not run again until server is rebooted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis, dts

This code is run every day

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = null;
string FilePath;
DTSEventListener EventListener = new DTSEventListener();
PackagePath = @"~\App_Data\Order ImportDev.dtsx";
FilePath = @"D:\Systems\Development System\Folder\ImportErrors.csv";
package = app.LoadPackage(Server.MapPath(PackagePath), EventListener);
DTSExecResult results = package.Execute(null,null, EventListener,null,null);
if (results == DTSExecResult.Failure)
{
    foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
    {
        body += local_DtsError.Description + " - " + local_DtsError.SubComponent;
    }
    using (SmtpClient SmtpHost = new SmtpClient("fghfefhfg"))
    {
        using (MailMessage MadeErrorsMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            MadeErrorsMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(user.Email));
            MadeErrorsMessage.From = new MailAddress("xxr@xxx", "Someone");
            MadeErrorsMessage.Subject = "Failed to load order(s)";
            MadeErrorsMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("admin@somewhere", "Jason"));
            MadeErrorsMessage.Body = body;
            SmtpHost.Send(MadeErrorsMessage);
        }
     }
}
package.Dispose();
package = null;
```

Occasionally the file fails to load with the following error:

> Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/Execute SQL Task :
>   Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "External
>   component has thrown an exception.". Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

If i run the package manually on the server the file load without error but after this has happen the server cannot load anymore file through ASP.Net until the whole server is rebooted.

I have tried just restarting SSIS and also SQL but that doesn't work only a complete server reboot solves the problem.

Comment: Check memory usage, specifically, if SQL Server has `max memory` configured to leave some available for SSIS and your code. If it's gobbled up most or all of available memory (as it's designed to do) you can get all sorts of interesting failures. Furthermore, check what's *actually* going wrong -- the error message just tells you that something failed somewhere executing the package, and the empty query text looks very fishy. Have you configured SSIS logging, and what does it say about the executions that fail?

Comment: There is about 10GB free memory on the server so i don't think that is the issue. The only error that i can get is the one i have posted, there are no other error messages.

Comment: If you wrap `DTSExecResult results = package.Execute(null,null, EventListener,null,null);` in a try/catch block, do you get more useful error information? Which server requires rebooting - the application server running the package or SQL Server? What is the package doing?

Comment: What is SSIS logging? Does the package execute at all when you get the error, and if it does what components does it execute? SSIS logging is configured separately (please don't ask me exactly how, it's been ages); at its most verbose, it logs *everything*.

Comment: @billinkc I have an event listener and logging is enabled but it just says "External component has thrown an exception.". The SQL Server is on the application server.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It doesn't execute at all, its failing at the first step. I have tried changing the data provider but that doesn't help.